# Losing data with pd.to_numeric

Tags: python

I'm importing a CSV file with cp1252 encoding (which I believe is the same as Latin 1). The last column of the CSV file is where the data-values are stored (ie the numbers I want to add up). This is headed 'Amount'. In the CSV file itself (opened in xlsx) I can see that there are about 500k values, and all the values are stored as numbers. However, when I'm reading this in Python, the data-values are read as an object rather than as int64.

To get around that, I've tried using pd.to_numeric. This generates an error report of 'unable to parse string' for data-values such as 21,893.93...which seems strange...and I can't see any special characters that this might relate to in the data

To avoid this error, I'm adding in an errors = 'coerce' term...but this then means that some of the data-values I want to be using are stripped out...and since it accounts for c 10% of my dataset this is problematic

My code looks likes this...

```
df = pd.read_csv("files.csv", encoding = 'latin-1')
df["Amount"] = df["Amount"].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')
```

How can I get Python to correctly read the data-values it can't parse?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us sample data by providing output of `df.head()`? @harrison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the commas with '' first, then to_numeric should work.

```
df["Amount"] = df["Amount"].str.replace(',', '')
```

Comment: Absolute legend. Thanks - you nailed it!!